# Ruby on Rails: Is it possible to link a column with a column on another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have models with deep associations in my Ruby on Rails API, sometimes 4 associations deep. For example:

```
Group has_many Subgroups has_many: Posts has_many: Comments
```

If I want to return `Group.title` with my comments, I need to say:

```
@comment.post.subgroup.group.title
```

Since this is way too many queries per Comment, I have added a column to the Comment table called group_title. This property is assigned when the Comment is created. Then every time the associated Group.title is updated, I have an after_update method on the Group model to update all associated Comment group_titles.

This seems like a lot of code to me and I find myself doing this often in this large scale app. Is there a way to link these 2 properties together to automatically update Comment.group_title every time its associated Group.title is updated?

Comment: No, there is no way to automatically do this without code like `after_update` or by adding deep `includes` or `joins` to your DB queries. Actually, this a perfect example of the need to make a decision: Optimize the DB for reads or for writes? What happens more often, that a comment is read or a group's title is changed?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar relation hierarchy, and solved it (maybe there are better solutions) with joins.

`Quarter` belongs_to `Detour` belongs_to `Forestry` belongs_to `Region`

For a given detour, I find region name with one query.

```
Quarter.select("regions.name AS region_name, forestries.name as forestry_name, \ 
 detours.name AS detour_name, quarters.*")
.joins(detour: [forestry: :region])
```

Sure, you can encapsulate it in a scope.

```
class Quarter
...
  scope :with_all_parents, -> {
    select("regions.name AS region_name, forestries.name as forestry_name, \ 
     detours.name AS detour_name, quarters.*")
    .joins(detour: [forestry: :region])
  }
end
```

You can also use same approach.

```
class Comment
...
  scope :with_group_titles, -> {
    select("groups.title AS group_title, comments.*").joins(post: [subgroup: :group])
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build hierarchies by using indirect associations:

```
class Group
  has_many :subgroups
  has_many :posts, through: :subgroups
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end

class Subgroup
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :subgroup
  has_one :group, through: :subgroup
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
  has_one :subgroup, through: :post 
  has_one :group, through: :post 
end
```

- [The `has_many :through` Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)
- [The `has_one :through` Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association)

This allows you to go from any end and rails will handle joining for you.

For example you can do:

```
@comment.group.title
```

Or do eager loading without passing a nested hash:

```
@comment = Comment.eager_load(:group).find(params[:id])
```

This however does not completely solve the performance issues related to joining deep nested hierarchies. This will still produce a monster of a join across four tables.

If you want to cache the title on the `comments` table you can use an ActiveRecord callback or you can define a [database trigger procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

```
class Group
  after_save :update_comments!
  def update_comments!
     self.comments.update_all(group_title: self.title)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by updating all the Comments from one side.

```
class Group
  after_update do 
    Comment.joins(post: [subgroup: :group]).where("groups.title=?", self.title).update_all(group_title: self.title)
  end 
end
```